# CreateFile() Error in console (powershell and CMD) after Anaconda installed

Tags: powershell, cmd, anaconda

After Anaconda installed, there are some error messages always displayed in my console, including CMD and PowerShell.
these error messages would be disappeared after Anaconda removed.

who encounters the same issue and know how to resolve it?

thanks very much!

Environment:

1. Windows 10 64bits v1903
2. Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64
3. or Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86

The error message when PowerShell started

```powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
PS C:\windows\system32> CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
```

The error message when debugging python file with python interpreter installed by Anaconda

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.175]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

c:\xm\github\python-study>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
CreateFile() Error: 5
```

Comment: 5 = Access Denied. See `net helpmsg 5`. Unless you are admin you may not write to system32 folder.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i assume this should be avoided or resolved by Anaconda.